# How to run both request/sampler successfully

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run http samplers sequentially for multiple requests. Where the output of 1 API response is the input of next API request. My concern is when I run with 5 users (for. e.g), then at given point of time it first executes 1st API with 5 users then second API with 5 users, in this process the API where input is required gets lost. Please help me on this.Actually I have used transaction controller also but here not sequentially api run,so getting file not found exception bcause of first api output response parameter is not passed to second api as a input parameter
I need a solution, where all the samplers are first executed for first user, then for second thread all the samplers are executed and so on.

Comment: Have you extracted the values from the first response using a JMeter [Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)?

Comment: Yes.. Using regular expression extractor

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter Thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down, if you have 2 samplers each user will always run 1st sampler then it will run 2nd sampler.

You can use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) in order to verify that the execution order is sequential.

[image]

If you want all the users to execute first sampler then all users to execute the second sampler - go for [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

If you want to get to the reason of the failure try saving the responses using i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) as it might be the case your "first" API fails silently and hence your correlation doesn't extract the value.